# How to drag a image from one button to another button in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, image, button, drag

Currently i am working in iPhone application, Using two buttons, then i set the image both button1 and button2, then i tried to drag a image from button1 to button2, Is it possible to do this? please help me

Thanks in Advance

```
 button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hearta.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button1.frame=CGRectMake(10, 60, 50, 50);
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(Button1Method) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button1];  

button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"club4.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button2.frame=CGRectMake(61, 60, 50, 50);
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(Button2Method) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get reference from [this demo](https://nodeload.github.com/radhar/HGKDragAndDropRecycleBin/zipball/master) project.

it's very nice.

Also another [link is here](http://www.radulucaciu.ro/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/ImageDrag.zip)

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one ways of doing this ...

1. You can either create a `UIImageView` on the click event or action of button1 and use animation to drag that image till button2 where you make the `imageview.image` equal to button2's image , side by side making the original imageview as nil so that you can show it disappear into button2.
2. Also, instead of buttons you can use `UIImageViews` directly and make and animation effect on the click methods there too.